# jQuery/javascript communicate between windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a window with a link.

When the link is clicked, a modal box opens (it's loading another page in an iframe).

The iframe contains a login. When the user logs in, I would like the modal box to close and send a message back to the original page.

How do I go about this?

Is there a javascript event or a way to dispatch a message between a window and a related iframe?

Comment: The iFrame can access the parent window using `window.top` or `window.parent`, at which point it can call any methods defined on the global scope of the parent window, such as using jQuery. `window.top.$("#someid").fadeIn();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call parent `window` JavaScript method from an iframe like this.

```
window.parent.methodName();
```

If you want to access any element from parent window.

```
$('elementSelector', window.parent).doAnyJQueryOperation();
```

If you want send a message to parent window.

```
window.parent.alert('Message from iframe');
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot...I wasn't even sure where to start.